# Google Sheet Stuck and unable to update, too many old versions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

**TLDR:**

Our Google Spreadsheet is broken and cannot be edited / saved. It keeps saying `Trying to reconnect. To edit offline, turn on offline sync when you reconnect`, and `Reconnecting`. Can it be due to the many versions saved? If so, what can be done if we don't want the sheet to change its ID?

Any help is highly appreciated!

**Detailed Background:**

We have a large Google Spreadsheet in our project (< 700k cells) and it's well under the 2 million cells size limit as described in [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en) .

We have been programmatically updating this sheet by creating CSVs in the google drive with python, then using Google App Script to update the sheet with contents from the CSVs.

It has been fine for several weeks, today we started to have an issue, that is, when we manually open the sheet, it just keeps saying "Trying to reconnect. To edit offline, turn on offline sync when you reconnect", and "Reconnecting". We can make no changes to the sheets.

We tried to use different browsers (chrome, firefox, edge) and different OS (Windows, Mac), and we still have the same issue. So I don't think it's anything related to firewall / browser configuration.

We tried to make a copy of the sheet, and we are able to make changes to the copy. We can also access any other sheets and make changes without any problem.

The only difference between the actual sheet and the copied sheets is probably that the actual sheet has a lot of old versions (it has been updated every 3 minutes for weeks). Can that be a reason of failure to edit?

Another possibility is that many other scripts read this sheet. Can this be why? (It will be a pain to stop all the scripts / redirect all the scripts to another Spreadsheet)

Thanks a lot in advance!

**Additional Details / Conclusions:**

- Using a database is definitely a better idea than a spreadsheet for such a large scale dataset.
- An ".edu" domain was used. I believe we are using the G Suite version.
- Just like the PC case, I am unable to make any changes when I use mobile version on Android.
- From various sources, it seems that the old versions cannot be deleted (http://www.sevenminutescientist.com/2016/06/03/no-you-cannot-remove-a-revision-history-from-a-google-doc/)
- When I look into the version history, it shows the following: "Google Docs encountered an error. Please try reloading this page, or coming back to it in a few minutes." I am unable to access any of the old versions.

Comment: Both of those could be reasons why you have problems editing that sheet. Or it could be something entirely on Google's end.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Do you have suggestions on how to fix it without changing the sheet ID? Is there a way to remove the old versions without making a new copy?

Comment: sorry to have to say it, but it may be time to stop using Google Sheets as a database and switch to a database. It´s not hard to imagine sheets struggling to display 700k cells which are being updated in the background. I suspect that even if you resolve this issue, you will simply hit further problems.

Comment: I would say it is on Googles end, reads would be very unlikely to affect the sheet but writes every 3 minutes for weeks could be causing an issue (I think you meant > 700k cells?) but you havn't provided much detail. Are you using a paid or edu domain? I'm sure their dev team would be interested to hear from you, they've been very helpful to me.

Comment: @pinoyyid Thanks! I did suggest using a real database but because of limitation and time and human resources we could not implement it. We thought as we were well below the size limit, it would be fine. 
If size is indeed the problem, we will try to delete some old obsolete data.

Comment: @JamesD What issue are you talking about? (there are around ~600k cells). We have been just using a .edu domain. Did you use a paid service? Did you email Google directly?

Comment: @I'-'I Thanks for the comment! I tried and it still fails to save in the moblie app.

Comment: @I'-'I Yes I can view it both on computer and mobile phone, but none of the changes made get saved.

Comment: @I'-'I From various sources, it seems that it's impossible to delete old version histories e.g. http://www.sevenminutescientist.com/2016/06/03/no-you-cannot-remove-a-revision-history-from-a-google-doc/

Comment: When I look into the version history, it shows the following:

"Google Docs encountered an error. Please try reloading this page, or coming back to it in a few minutes."

I am unable to access any of the old versions.

Comment: Although I don't think you'll get an answer, Please [edit] to include all these details in the question itself and highlight these error messages. Send feedback to google and open a issue in the issue tracker

Comment: Done!

It seems like the issue checker is only for Google internal use and people who collaborate with Google teams. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Issued opened here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112158879

Comment: @Matthew If revisions are indeed the issue, You can update a file without creating a newRevision using Advanced Drive services. See newRevision [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update). Seems you can also delete a revision. See [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/revisions/delete)

Answer (score 0):

Having issues with Google Drive constantly disconnecting you in Chrome? Error message: “Trying to connect. To edit offline, turn on offline sync when you reconnect”

This issue was encountered on a PC running Windows 10 64bit and Google Chrome (happens in the 32-bit and 64-bit versions). It doesn’t appear to happen in Firefox.

Cause: Kaspersky SSL Scanning (although it may still be an issue in Chrome as it doesn’t happen with other browsers and will likely be fixed by one of the parties soon)

Solution: Disable Kaspersky 2015 Encrypted Connection Scanning. Settings > Additional > Network > Disable encrypted connection scanning. NOTE: even if you disable Kaspersky via the temporary disable feature Google Docs still doesn’t work you have to turn off Encrypted Connection Scanning as it’s obviously always running even when Kaspersky is temporarily stopped (another bug as turning Kaspersky off should disable this).

Comment: use [markdonwn](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) format

Comment: thanks for the info but it doesn't seem to be directly relevant to the question asked