# Google Spreadsheet DB Import Error: Couldn't save document with id [--ID--]: Document is too large

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

For the past 48 hours all of the sudden all my queries to import data from my DB into my sheet are failing with this error:

> Google Spreadsheet Couldn't save document with id [--ID--]: Document
>   is too large.

Nothing has changend in the size of my DB.
There just about 1100 rows to pull. It was working for years.
Couldn't even find this error on google.

Any idea what to do?

Code of script in google sheets:

```
function updateS() {

    // Replace the variables in this block with real values.
    var ServerIP = 'zzzzzzz'; 
    var SQL_Port = 'zzzzzzzzzz';
    var SQL_Usr = 'zzzzzzzzz';
    var SQL_Pwd = 'zzzzzzzz';
    var SQL_DB = 'zzzzzzzzzzzzz';

    var connectorInstance = 'jdbc:mysql://' + ServerIP+':'+SQL_Port;
    var ConnectString = connectorInstance+'/'+SQL_DB;



    var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(ConnectString, SQL_Usr, SQL_Pwd);
    //Executes the queries
    var execStmt = conn.createStatement();

    //Gets and Sets the Current Spreadsheet as Active
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    doc.setActiveSheet(doc.getSheetByName('Sheet1'));


    var mysqlQuery = execStmt.executeQuery("call my_call()"); //table name is product
    var cell = doc.getRange('A2');

    // loop through result object, setting cell values to database data
    var row = 0;
    while(mysqlQuery.next()) {
    for(var i=0; i<13; i++) { // 3 fields per record

    cell.offset(row, i).setValue(mysqlQuery.getString(i+1));
    }
    row++;
    }

    mysqlQuery.close();
    execStmt.close();
    conn.close();



}
```

Comment: Could you provide any error details like error from your logs, so that the community will have an idea what is the problem?

Comment: This is the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51407550/google-sheet-stuck-and-unable-to-update-too-many-old-versions no solution other than open a new sheet.